# Spring WebClient pass inactive access token to API calls

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring boot 3.0.4 with Java 17. WebClient API call passes inactive access tokens time to time when calling the APIs.

Here is error scenario that occurred. New access token is generated daily on 4.00 PM. After that again new access token is generated on 4.45 PM by force. When new access token generated old access token will inactive. API calls after 4.45 PM access token pass through WebClient is previous inactive one. As per my knowledge Spring will automatically calls and get new token if an Access Token is invalid. This issue is occurred time to time.

Here is a Sample of Access token Response.

```
{
    "access_token": "********-*****-****-****-***********",
    "scope": "am_application_scope default",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 20138
}
```

WebClient Configuration as below.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class Oauth2WebClientConfig {

    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public Oauth2WebClientConfig(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }
    // == Oauth2 Configuration ==

    // == Oauth2 Configuration ==
    @Bean
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistration() {
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("custom")
                .tokenUri(env.getProperty("token-uri"))
                .clientId(env.getProperty("client-id"))
                .clientSecret(env.getProperty("client-secret"))
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .scope(env.getProperty("scope"))
                .build();
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
    }

    @Bean
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService() {
        return new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistration());
    }

    // == WebFlux Configuration ==
    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistration, ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistration, authorizedClientService));
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("custom");

        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
                    exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest());
                    exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logResponse());
                })
                .build();
    }

    // == Log Request ==
    private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Request: \n")
                    .append(clientRequest.method())
                    .append(" ")
                    .append(clientRequest.headers())
                    .append(" ")
                    .append(clientRequest.url());
            clientRequest
                    .headers()
                    .forEach((name, values) -> values.forEach(value -> sb
                            .append("\n")
                            .append(name)
                            .append(":")
                            .append(value)));
            log.info(sb.toString());

            return Mono.just(clientRequest);
        });
    }

    // == Log Response ==
    private ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Response: \n")
                    .append("Status: ")
                    .append(clientResponse.rawStatusCode())
                    .append(" ")
                    .append(clientResponse.headers())
                    .append(" ")
                    .append("Body : ")
                    .append(clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class));
            clientResponse
                    .headers()
                    .asHttpHeaders()
                    .forEach((key, value1) -> value1.forEach(value -> sb
                            .append("\n")
                            .append(key)
                            .append(":")
                            .append(value)));
            log.info(sb.toString());
            return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        });
    }
    // == WebFlux Configuration ==
}
```

Here is the API call using WebClient.

```
 String response = Objects.requireNonNull(webClient.get()
                            .uri(reqUrl)
                            .header("TRACE_ID", traceId)
                            .retrieve())
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, resp -> resp.bodyToMono(String.class).flatMap(error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException(error))))
                    .bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .retry(2)
                    .doOnError(error -> log.error("API error has occurred {} : TRACE_ID : {}", error.getMessage(), traceId))
                    .block();
            log.info("response {} : TRACE_ID : {}", response, traceId);
```

Does anyone has an idea about why webclient will pass the inactive Access Token?